# Stop arbitrary function execution

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, swift4, grand-central-dispatch

For the purposes of this question, assume that I need to run some function on some object and that function will take a long time to execute (minutes). Also assume that I have no control over this function (*). **How do I now cancel this function's execution?**

I want to run it in a background thread to keep the main thread free and I could do that with GCD, `NSOperation` or `NSThread`. However, as far as I know, none of these support forced stopping. They can all be cancelled, but this cancellation must be implemented in the function itself - but I don't have access to that function, so I can't do that. The closest I got was using `NSThread` and `exit()`, but unfortunately it can't be applied to a instance variable (see the code example). My current plan is to try to send a notification and observe that within the object/function and kill the thread from within using `Thread.exit()`. I'm justing wondering if there is a "cleaner" or easier way, either built-in or 3rd party.

```
let someObject = Object()

// Using GCD
dispatchQueue.async { someObject.expensiveFunction() }

// Using NSOperation
operationQueue.addOperation { someObject.expensiveFunction() }

// Using NSThread
let thread = Thread { someObject.expensiveFunction() }
thread.exit() // exit is not available on an instance
```

(*) In this case I do have control over the function and could implement an actual cancellation, but due to the libraries I'm using, this would require a lot of refactoring.

Comment: You can check if your operation `isCancelled` periodically inside its `main()`, then you'll be able to stop it using `myOperation.cancel()`. Same for `DispatchWorkItem` btw.

Comment: Terminating a thread from outside of it is inherently unsafe. It might be in the middle of a call to a system library which uses state or resources shared with the other threads in the process. If the one thread is terminated unceremoniously, it can leave that state in an inconsistent state that will affect the other threads. For example, if the `malloc()` implementation uses locks, you might terminate a thread while it holds a lock and then no other thread will be able to `malloc()`. If you must do something like this, probably a separate process (maybe an XPC service) is best.

Comment: @KenThomases This seems to limit my options quite a bit, but I think I just avoided quite a bit of headache from weird crashes - thanks!